# Jackson deserialize inner collection

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have an issue with deserialization of inner collection:
Imagine there are two classes:

```
// RootClass.java
package somepackage;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class RootClass {
    public List getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @JsonSerialize(contentAs = Item.class)
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
}

//Item.java
package somepackage;

class Item {
    String name;

    public Item() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Item(String cat) {
        name = cat;
    }
}

// main class
package somepackage;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SampleCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        RootClass root = new RootClass();
        root.items.add(new Item("cat"));
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(root);
        RootClass root2 = mapper.readValue(json, RootClass.class);
        Item item = (Item) root2.items.get(0);
    }
}
```

I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class somepackage.Item (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; somepackage.Item is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

According to javadoc `@JsonSerialize(contentAs = Item.class)` on the collection would have help me, but it wouldn't. **The question is: What am i missing?**

If it is not about this annotation i suspect there is a standard way to deal with the problem (i do not want to create custom deserializers).

Most questions on collection deserialization are about situation when root object is a collection itself, but this is not the case for me.

jackson 2.9.8
java 11.0.2 OpenJDK x64

Comment: You can always use generics: `List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @MichałZiober, ok thanks, but i expected that it will work without them as well. I will try to do deep debugging

Comment: It is not possible to properly deserialise this `JSON` without type information. What do you want to achieve? Do you want to have one root model for many different types not only `Item`?

Comment: I meant with the help of `@JsonSerialize(contentAs = Item.class)`

Comment: I have figured out that if i specify generic collection in **setter** method: `public void setItems(List<Item> items)` then the problem goes away. Specifying generics in field or on **getter** or putting `@JsonSerialize(contentAs = Item.class)` anywhere does not help

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with the basic form of your code.  What you're trying to do will work.  You just have problems with your code, starting with the fact that it won't even compile since you call a constructor on Item that takes a String, and yet you define no such constructor.  You also need getters for Jackson to work with.

Here's a version of your code that works:

```
class RootClass {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}

class Item {
    String name;
    Item() {}
    Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] argsx) throws IOException{

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    RootClass root = new RootClass();
    root.items.add(new Item("cat"));
    RootClass root2 = null;
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(root);
    root2 = mapper.readValue(json, RootClass.class);
    Item item = root2.items.get(0);
    System.out.println(item.getName());
}
```

Output:

```
cat
```

Comment: Hi @Steve sorry if i mislead you but i intentionally skipped trivial code lines (accessors, constructors). I will add full project then

Comment: if you say this code works for you then means there is an issue with my setup, maybe particular versions of jackson and java

Comment: That's what I'm saying.  If you've tried my code, you should put exactly what you've tried in your question, along with the error you're getting.  I'd like to see what error you're getting.  This code should work with any at all recent version of Jackson, and the Java version shouldn't matter if it compiles.  Tell us what versions of those things you're using. - for the benefit of those who follow, having a question with code that actually compiles will be helpful in itself.